# Bold link to parent URL using jQuery (on wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've used this (see code below) to bold the link of the current page. e.g.
http://somewebsite.com/parent-page/current-page  (the names of the sections are used as examples)

This will bold all links pointing to current-page, but I want to modify it to bold all links to the parent page (http://somewebsite.com/parent-page):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

       $("header a").each(function(){
               if ($(this).attr("href") == window.location.pathname){
                       $(this).addClass("current-second-menu");
               }
       });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a minor change

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

       $("header a").each(function(){
               // if ($(this).attr("href") == window.location.pathname){
               if ($(this).attr("href") == window.location.pathname.slice(0, window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/'))){
                       $(this).addClass("current-second-menu");
               }
       });
});
```